# Component getter triggers re-render even though the internal values don't change

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm having trouble understanding the following behaviour, I am not looking for a fix, I'm just trying to understand why this happens this way:

I'm having a really basic component, with a `{{ title }}` binding in my template. That title is bound to a getter that returns a new Date. When just returning the Date, the component will only render once, which I think is expected behaviour.

However, when I add a `setInterval` in my `ngOnInit` to update **a completly different value**, the view will re-render with the a new date. Why is that? There is no data binding in the view to the `_test` value.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  private _test: string = " ";

  public get title(): string {
    return new Date().toUTCString();
  }

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    setInterval(() => {
      this._test = "";
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

Here's a [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nkj0n780yj) if you want to see it in action. I am not looking for a fix here, just want to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how change detection works: the `setTimeout` callback is executed, Angular knows about it thanks to zone.js, but it can't possibly know what the callback is doing. So it reevaluates all the expressions used in the templates to know if their value has changed, and if they have, it modifies the DOM accordingly.

Returning a new Date from a getter bound in the template is a terrible idea: the getter will be called at each change detection, and the value returned will always be different. You absolutely don't want that. The getter should be idempotent: when called twice in a row, it should return the same value.

Comment: So any callback execution triggers change detection for the entire component?

Comment: No. It triggers change detection for the whole application. Not just the component.

Comment: That sounds surprisingly ressource-heavy, but fair enough. Thank you for the answer.